# How does MDC logging works even though there is no MDC.put() in a method?

Tags: java, rest, logging, mdc

I am examining a code written before and it is the first time I have seen MDC logging. I was trying to understand how it works but there a couple of classes which does not have MDC at all, yet the logs are written to the log file.

I understand that if a method is called from another method and if the caller method has MDC logging then the logs in callee method will also be written in the log file etc.

However in the project I am looking, there is a REST method with @GET annotation and it simply returns another method **from the same class**. Like this:

```
@GET
public Response methodName (@PathParam ...){
    return doSomething(..)
}
```

Inside this *doSomething* method the first thing it does is to print some logs like below and *"print this"* is written to the log file with the (key,value) format that was used for other classes that use MDC. For example in overall project MDC is used like this;

```
MDC.put(uId, "csel@example.com")
```

and the below is written to log file like this: "*csel@example.com print this*"

```
public Response doSomething(){
      if (logger.isEnabledFor(Level.TRACE)) {
           logger.trace("print this");
      }
       ...
}
```

There is no MDC logic in that class but the log is present in log file in MDC format.
How does this log is written to the log file? Could you please help me understand this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MDC, this is normal logging. Why do you think MDC is involved here? MDC is about adding extra context data to the logging.

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the most important part, it is written in MDC format to the log file with key value being present at the start of log line. I edited the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The whole idea of MDC is that you set a value into the MDC at some point, and all logging in the same thread will use that information when logging (until the value is replaced or removed), without the other parts of your code being aware of MDC. This happens transparently for you inside the logging implementation you use.